# How to find the length of diagonal of a rhombus

Tags: geometry

suppose,only the length of the side of a rhombus is given then how can I find the length of the diagonals?(without measuring the angle)
Is there any equation where the side is related to the diagonal only?

Comment: Don't be silly. If all you know is the side length, then there's an infinity of qualifying rhombi, right? and they have different diagonals, right?

Comment: Knowing only the length of a side it is impossible to know the length of the diagonals. You're going to need more info.

Comment: How?@GerryMyerson

Comment: How what? Please express yourself in complete sentences, the better to aid my understanding. Or just think about starting with a square, and squashing it.

Comment: @Titom There exists a square with unit length sides. There also exists a rhombus with unit length sides and angles $45^{\circ},135^{\circ},45^{\circ},135^{\circ}$ respectively. Hence more than two different rhombi have the same edge lengths and so more information (probably the internal angles) is needed.

Comment: I don't know why someone decided to overwrite an old question with a different one — rolled back.

Comment: (...and now we have answers to two different questions in one place...)

Answer (score 3):

Consider any line segment AC whose length is $ < 2x $ ( $x$ being the length of the side of rhombus in question. )

From A cut an arc of radius $x$, then from C. They intersect say at B.

Now, you have an isosceles triangle ABC where $ AB = BC = x $

Reflect point B in the line segment AC to get a point outside the triangle, name it D.

Now we have : $ AB = AD = x $ and $ CB = CD = x $, so what do you have ?

We have a rhombus ABCD of side length $x$, whose diagonal can be anything between $0$ and $2x$.

If it were just one rhombus that existed you would not have arbitrary length diagonals to start with but only two distinct values the short and long diagonal.

So the rhombus in question is not unique !!

Comment: Also if you compute the area : $$ \mbox{ area of a rhombus } = \frac{1}{2}d_1 d_2 $$ where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are respective length of its diagonals.

Choosing $ 0 < d_1 < 2x $, $$ (\frac{1}{2}d_2)^2 = x^2 - (\frac{1}{2}{d_1})^2 $$ by Pythagoras Theorem as the diagonals of a rhombus perpendicularly bisect each other. 

So area rhombus of side length $x$ is $$ \frac{1}{2} d_1 \{2 \sqrt{x^2 - (\frac{1}{2}d_1)^2}\} $$

Answer (score 1):

Following from the comments, the best we can do is give a relation between the sum of the square of the lengths of the diagonals. If $ABCD$ is a rhombus with side length $x$ then, by the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law), and because we know each side has equal length, we know that $4x^2=|AC|^2+|BD|^2$ where $|AC|$ is the length of the diagonal from $A$ to $C$ and similarly for $|BD|$.

In the case of a square, we get $|AC|=|BD|$ and so $2x^2=|AC|^2\Rightarrow|AC|=\sqrt{2}\cdot x$.